# assign dynamic array in a function and send it back to the caller in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I have been using java for long time but for some reason I need to use C (ANSI C not C++) to write a simple code. I need to pass the pointer from outside to a function, allocate some memory to the pointer and assign some values also before the function return. I have my code like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test(int *a)
{
  int n=3;
  // I have to call another function t determine the size of the array
  n = estimatesize(); // n >=3
  // I tried fix size n=10 also

  a = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 2;
  a[2] = 3;
}

void main(void)
{
  int *s=NULL;
  test(s);
  printf("%d %d %d", s[0], s[1], s[2]);
}
```

I don't know why the code crashes. I thought at the beginning it is estimatesize() return wrong number but even I fix n to 10, the error still there. So I cannot pass a pointer to a function for memory allocation? If so, how can I dynamically create memory inside a function and pass it out? I know it may be a safe problem in this way but I just want to know if it is possible and how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to this: Either *return* the pointer from the function, or pass the argument *by reference*.

For the first one, you simply don't take any arguments, instead you return the pointer:

```
int *test(void)
{
    int *a = malloc(...);
    ...
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *s = test();
    ...
}
```

For the second one, you need to pass the address of the pointer, in other words a pointer to the pointer, using the address-of operator `&`:

```
void test(int **a)
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        (*a)[i] = i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *s;
    test(&s);
    ...
}
```

---

The reason it doesn't work now, is because the pointer (`s` in `main`) is passed by copying it. So the function `test` have a local copy, whose scope is only in the `test` function. Any changes to `a` in the `test` function will be lost once the function returns. And as `s` is copied for the argument, that means that `s` in `main` never actually changes value, it's still `NULL` after the function call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get your idea but I tried your code, it doesn't work. Again, it seems that you are implementing it in C++ but I need ANSI C and only have ANSI C compiler.

Comment: @user1285419 No, both solutions are pure C, there is no C++ in it.

Comment: @user1285419 Arrays not withstanding, remember this mantra: C is a by-value parameter language. If you want to pass a parameter by-address, then passing an *address* is exactly what you need to do: pass the address of the target variable and declare the parameter to be a formal pointer-to-type. And the "type" makes *no difference*. Whatever the target variable type is, a pointer to that type is the way the parameter  should be declared ( in Joachim's code above, the type is `int*`). (and +1 on the answer, btw).

Comment: I think the syntax you define i in the loop only works in c++. In ANSI C, we need to define all variables before the code. Anyway, by fixing that, I have it run in now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1285419 Declaring variables in a `for` loop like that has been standardized for a very long time (since the C99 standard). What compiler and what version of it are you using?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Really, I know very little about C/C++. But the compiler I have in my lab is very very old, I don't know much about it. But I have it tested, it doesn't support internal variable defined in the loop. Thanks again anyway.